# Dead objects eating up memory

Tags: c#, .net, memory-management, memory-leaks

Within my application, I'm having memory usage issues where the Loh is filling up with dead objects, 1.5GB worth (seen below). The objects are being stored in a Byte array.

[image]

I've tried to clean it up by running the following code to reduce memory usage but it doesn't seem to be functioning.

```
private static void OnScavengeProfileCache(object data)
{
 // loop until the runtime is shutting down
while(HostingEnvironment.ShutdownReason == ApplicationShutdownReason.None)
{
    // NOTE: Right now we only do the scavenge when traffic is temporarily low,
    // to try to amortize the overhead of scavenging the cache into a low utilization period.
    // We also only scavenge if the process memory usage is very high.
    if (s_timerNoRequests.ElapsedMilliseconds >= 10000)
    {
        // We dont want to scavenge under lock to avoid slowing down requests,
        // so we get the list of keys under lock and then incrementally scan them
        IEnumerable<string> profileKeys = null;
        lock (s_profileCache)
        {
             profileKeys = s_profileCache.Keys.ToList();
        }


        ScavengeProfileCacheIncremental(profileKeys.GetEnumerator());
    }

    // wait for a bit
    Thread.Sleep(60 * 1000);
}
}

private static void ScavengeProfileCacheIncremental(IEnumerator<string> profileKeys)
{
if (s_thisProcess.PrivateMemorySize64 >= (200 * 1024 * 1024) ) // 3Gb at least
{
    int numProcessed = 0;
    while(profileKeys.MoveNext())
    {
        var key = profileKeys.Current;
        Profile profile = null;
        if (s_profileCache.TryGetValue(key, out profile))
        {
            // safely check/remove under lock, its fast but makes sure we dont blow away someone currently being addded
            lock (s_profileCache)
            {
                if (DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(profile.CreateTime).TotalMinutes > 5)
                {
                    // can clear it out
                    s_profileCache.Remove(key);
                }
            }
        }

        if (++numProcessed >= 10)
        {
            // stop this scan and check memory again
            GCSettings.LargeObjectHeapCompactionMode = GCLargeObjectHeapCompactionMode.CompactOnce;
            GC.Collect(); 
            break;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Any tips on how I should go about cleaning up memory usage here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Large Arrays, and LOH Fragmentation. What is the accepted convention?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29520108/34092)

Comment: Should you count even the profiles that you don't remove here?

Comment: `MemoryCache` is likely the right solution since the data will automatically expire - you don't need to do it manually like you are here.

Comment: Memory caching is a foreign topic to me, any advice on how I could go about implementing it? @mjwills

Comment: I'd suggest reading the docs for `MemoryCache` and having a play with it, and then creating a new question with any specific questions you have.

Answer (score -1):

try System.GC.Collect() forces garbage collector to run.
This should clean out dead objects

Comment: By itself that will not deal with the LOH.